# How to include end date while calculating time difference in years?(Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Please share your feedback on this problem. I need to calculate difference in 'years' and store it under a new column 'Age'.

While the formula works fine, it gives me incorrect output when I consider dates starting from 1st Jan of any year

For example: difference in years between 1st Jan 2019 and 31st Dec 2021 is 3 years - this includes end date in calculation. My result shows 2 years.

Here are the 2 date columns from which I am deriving the difference:

[image: columns and age output]

However, when I consider dates from 1st Jan - the result shows me one year less:

[image: Incorrect Output for 1st Jan entries]

Here is the code I used to calculate difference:

```
UPDATE animals
SET age = abs(benchmarkdate :: date - birthdate :: date)/ 365;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I guess your requirement is a bit different, because you want difference + 1 when birthdate is on 1-Jan else just the difference. In that case you could use where condition and achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EXTRACT` here and then take a difference of only the year components on the two dates:

```sql
UPDATE animals
SET age = EXTRACT(year FROM benchmarkdate) - EXTRACT(year FROM birthdate);
```

Note that you might even want to avoid doing this update, and instead just compute the age when you select.  If you foresee the need to frequently do such an update, that would be a good indicator that you probably should change your approach.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. The command above doesnt work for 1st Jan cases, I am still getting one year less. For example: 1st Jan 2019 - 31 Dec 2021 (end date included) comes to 2 years using the above code, the output should be 3 years instead.

Comment: I don't consider that difference to be 3 years.

Comment: So what would your expected result be from 2-Jan-2019 to 31-Dec-2021, or 3-Jan-2019 to 31-Dec-2021, ... At what point do you change to (year-year)+1 to just (year-year).  BTW you might want to check-out the [age](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html) function.